# How to convert this term to a Hypergeometric function?

Tags: special-functions, complex, series-expansion, conversion

```
term=8*(-1)^(1/4)*Sqrt[b]*q0^(3/2)*\[Kappa]*
 EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[((-1)^(1/4)*Sqrt[b]*r)/Sqrt[q0]], -1]
```

1. This is a physical term and it is not convenient to appear $I$ (complex number) in the solutions. How can I convert this term to a more familiar function (in my field) like $Hypergeometric$ one, without any imaginary number? Is it possible?
2. Moreover, how can I expand this term using `Series[term,{b,Infinity,0}]`? The assumptions are: 
   $q0$ and $b$ are real parameters, $r>0$, and $\kappa>0$.
3. As the final question, how about these terms (in the form of `Hypergeometric` and its expansion series about $\infty$.):

```
term2=((4/3 + (4*I)/3)*Sqrt[b]*G*Pi^(1/4)*Q^(5/2)*
  Sqrt[1 + (4*b^2*Pi*r^4)/Q^2]*
  EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[((1 + I)*Sqrt[b]*Pi^(1/4)*r)/Sqrt[Q]], 
   -1])/(r*Sqrt[Q^2 + 4*b^2*Pi*r^4])
```

```
term3=- (I*b*E^(b^2*C[1])*Sqrt[1 - r^4/E^(2*b^2*C[1])]*
   EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[Sqrt[-E^(-(b^2*C[1]))]*r], -1])/
  (Sqrt[-E^(-(b^2*C[1]))]*Sqrt[E^(2*b^2*C[1]) - r^4])
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your first question, if we gather the factors into a single variable `z`, there's a simple hypergeometric function:

```
f[z_] = (-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z], -1];
g[z_] = -z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -z^4];
```

These two functions are the same, even though `FullSimplify` cannot prove it:

```
Series[f[z] - g[z], {z, 0, 100}]
(* O[z]^101 *)

Plot[Abs[f[z] - g[z]], {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Your term is

```
term == 8 Sqrt[b] q0^(3/2) κ f[(Sqrt[b] r)/Sqrt[q0]]
(* True *)
```

The series expansion follows from the hypergeometric function:

```
Assuming[r > 0 && Element[q0, Reals], 
  Series[8 Sqrt[b] q0^(3/2) κ g[(Sqrt[b] r)/Sqrt[q0]], {b, ∞, 0}] //FullSimplify]
(* the series expansion *)
```

The second term can be expressed in terms of the same function $f(z)$:

```
Assuming[Q > 0, 
  term2 == (4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b] G π^(1/4) Q^(3/2))/(3 r) *
    f[(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b] π^(1/4) r)/Sqrt[Q]] // FullSimplify]
(* True *)
```

The third term too:

```
Assuming[Element[{b, C[1]}, Reals], 
  term3 == -b E^((b^2 C[1])/2) (-1)^(-1/4) *
    f[(-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[E^(-b^2 C[1])] r] // FullSimplify]
(* True *)
```

### update: derivation

This is how I found the hypergeometric expression. Start with a series expansion around $z=0$,

```
f[z_] = (-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z], -1];
Series[f[z], {z, 0, 50}]
(* -z  + z^5/10 - z^9/24 + 5*z^13/208 - ... *)
```

We see that all terms are of the form $z^{1+4n}$ with integer $n$. The series coefficients are

```
Table[{n, SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, 0, 1 + 4 n}]}, {n, 0, 10}]
(* {{0, -1}, {1, 1/10}, {2, -1/24}, {3, 5/208}, {4, -35/2176},
    {5, 3/256}, {6, -231/25600}, {7, 429/59392}, {8, -195/32768},
    {9, 12155/2424832}, {10, -46189/10747904}} *)
```

Find a closed-form expression for these coefficients:

```
FindSequenceFunction[%, n]
(* ((-1)^(1 + n) Pochhammer[1/2, n])/((-3 + 4 (1 + n)) Pochhammer[1, n]) *)
```

Sum them to infinity to find a hypergeometric expression:

```
Sum[% z^(1 + 4 n), {n, 0, ∞}]
(* -z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -z^4] *)
```

Comment: Dear @Roman, would you please introduce a reference or maybe a convert command in `Mathematica`? Actually I have two other terms!

Comment: @PerfectFluid yes, see update.

Comment: Amazing derivation!

Comment: @Roman: I added another term (`term2`). Would you plz see it too? tnx.

Comment: @PerfectFluid see above: `term2` is not very different from `term` and can also be expressed with the same function `f[z]`.

Answer (score 10):

Match up power series and solve for parameters for `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d x]`:

```
ClearAll[reduce2F1, iReduce2F1];
Options[reduce2F1] = {"ExtraTerms" -> 2};
reduce2F1[expr_, x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  reduce2F1[expr, x, True, OptionsPattern[]];
reduce2F1[expr_, x_, assum_: True, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{res = iReduce2F1[expr, x, assum, OptionValue["ExtraTerms"]]}, 
   res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]];
reduce2F1[expr_, __] := expr;
iReduce2F1[expr_, x_, assum_, xtra_] := 
  Module[{deg, coeffs, redcoeffs, varcoeff, power, commonfactor, ni, 
    nn, den, h2f1, res, a, b, c, d},
   deg = 4;
   While[
    Total@ Replace[
        Series[expr, {x, 0, deg}][[3]],
        {0 -> 0, _ -> 1}, 1] < 5 + xtra && deg < 100,
    deg++];
   {coeffs, ni, nn, den} =
      (List @@ Series[expr, {x, 0, deg}, Assumptions -> assum])[[3 ;; 6]];
   coeffs = Simplify[coeffs, assum];
   Quiet@ Check[
     {{power}} = DeleteDuplicates@
       Differences@ SparseArray[coeffs]["NonzeroPositions"], 
     Return[$Failed, Module]];
   redcoeffs = DeleteCases[coeffs, 0];
   varcoeff = Times @@ Intersection @@ 
       Replace[
        Replace[Ratios@redcoeffs, {p_Times :> List @@ p, n_ :> {n}}, 1], 
        z_?NumericQ /; Negative[z] :> Sequence[-1, -z], 2];
   redcoeffs = redcoeffs/varcoeff^(Range[0, Length@coeffs, power]/power) // 
     Simplify[#, assum] &;
   commonfactor = redcoeffs[[1]];
   redcoeffs = redcoeffs/commonfactor;
   h2f1 = Solve[redcoeffs[[2 ;; 5 + xtra]] == 
      Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d x], {x, 0, 5 + xtra - 1}][[3, 2 ;; 5 + xtra]]
      {a, b, c, d}];
   If[ListQ[h2f1] && FreeQ[{a, b, c, d} /. h2f1, a | b | c | d],
    commonfactor * x^(ni/den) * 
      (Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d*varcoeff*x^(power/den)] /. First@h2f1),
    $Failed
    ]
   ];
```

*Update 3: A simpler approach*

It is perhaps simpler to compute a general substitution for the particular replacement of `EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[..], -1]` with a hypergeometric function, which seems to be common to all the OP's examples:

```
ClearAll[ellFTo2F1];
ellFTo2F1[EllipticF[I ArcSinh[z_], -1]] = 
 reduce2F1[EllipticF[I ArcSinh[z], -1], z, True]
ellFTo2F1[e_] := e;

(*  I z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, z^4]  *)
```

Then the following will convert the OP's examples:

```
expr /. e_EllipticF :> ellFASinh[e] // Simplify[#, <assum>] &
```

Example:

```
term3 /. e_EllipticF :> ellFASinh[e] // 
 Simplify[#, {b, r, C[1]} \[Element] Reals] &

(*  b r Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, E^(-2 b^2 C[1]) r^4]  *)
```

---

*Older examples*

OP's examples:

```
hyper = reduce2F1[term, b, q0 > 0 && r > 0]
(*  -8 b q0 r κ Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -((b^2 r^4)/q0^2)]  *)

Series[term - hyper, {b, 0, 25}, Assumptions -> q0 > 0 && r > 0]
(*  O[b]^26  *)

hyper2 = reduce2F1[term2, b, Q > 0 && G > 0 && r > 0, 
  "ExtraTerms" -> 0]
(*  -(8/3) b G Sqrt[π] Q Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -((4 b^2 π r^4)/Q^2)]  *)

Series[term2 - hyper2, {b, 0, 25}, Assumptions -> Q > 0 && G > 0 && r > 0]
(*  O[b]^26  *)
```

The option `"ExtraTerms"` sets how many terms of the power series beyond the necessary degree 4 for determining `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are used to "verify" the reduced expression is a `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d x]` function.  In other words, there is no guarantee that if `reduce2F1` returns a hypergeometric function, it is correct.

*Update:* The `Solve` command in `reduce2F1` may be replaced by the form

```
Solve[redcoeffs[[;; 5 + xtra]] == 
  Series[e Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d x], {x, 0, 5 + xtra - 1}][[3]],
 {e, a, b, c, d}]
```

Here the parameters `d` and `e` replace the need for `varcoeff` and `commonfactor`, so the lines from `varcoeff =...` to `...= redcoeffs/commonfactor` may be omitted.  This makes the code simpler and easier to understand, imo; however, it runs about about 10% to 60% slower on the OP's examples. (Note: timing is made difficult because `Series` and `Simplify` cache results. `ClearSystemCache[]` is needed to get reliable timings.)

*Update 2: The new `term31`:*

Here the argument is `E^(-2 b^2 C[1])`, which takes a substitution to convert to a variable `z`.  There is an extra factor of `b` that should not be included in the transformation.  In fact, in the substitution `bsub`, `b` might be plus or minus the square root, and algebraically it works in this case except for the factor `b`.  One way to handle it is to do the reverse substitution `Reverse[bsub]` before the inverse substitution `zsub`:

```
bsub = b -> Sqrt[Log[1/z]/C[1]];
zsub = z -> E^(-(b^2*C[1]));

hyper3 = term3 /. bsub /. Sqrt[-z] -> I*Sqrt[z] /. 
     e_EllipticF :> reduce2F1[e, z, r > 0] /. Reverse[bsub] /. 
   zsub // Simplify[#, {b, r, C[1]} \[Element] Reals] &

(*  b r Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, E^(-2 b^2 C[1]) r^4]  *)
```

Alternatively, manually get rid of the `b` factor, convert, and then multiply by `b`:

```
hyper3 = term3/b /. bsub /. Sqrt[-z] -> I*Sqrt[z] /. 
     e_EllipticF :> reduce2F1[e, z, r > 0] /. zsub // 
   Simplify[#, {b, r, C[1]} \[Element] Reals] &;
hyper3 = b*hyper3
```

Comment: Dear @Michael, thank you so much. Your answer was very useful too. However, I couldn't choose both of them :(

Comment: @PerfectFluid You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

This is a slightly simpler version of what Michael and Roman did, through leveraging some knowledge about elliptic integrals. First, some observations (using Roman's simplification):

```
D[{(-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z], -1],
   -z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -z^4]}, z] // Simplify
   {-(1/Sqrt[1 + z^4]), -(1/Sqrt[1 + z^4])}

{(-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z], -1],
 -z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -z^4]} /. z -> 0
   {0, 0}
```

Effectively, we are considering the integral

$$\int_z^0\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$$

I have always complained that *Mathematica* often needlessly inserts complex numbers in its elliptic integral results even when it can be avoided, and this case is no exception. Using [formula 263.50 from Byrd and Friedman](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0) instead, we obtain the equivalent result

```
InverseJacobiCN[(z^2 - 1)/(z^2 + 1), 1/2]/2 - EllipticK[1/2]
```

As for obtaining a hypergeometric representation, recall the [binomial series](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.6.E7):

```
Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[1/Sqrt[1 + z^4], {z, 0, 4 k}], k ∈ Integers && k >= 0]
   ((-1)^k (-1/2 + k)!)/(Sqrt[π] k!)
```

Check:

```
Sum[((-1)^k (-(1/2) + k)!)/(Sqrt[π] k!) z^(4 k), {k, 0, ∞}]
   1/Sqrt[1 + z^4]
```

Integrate termwise:

```
Sum[((-1)^k (-(1/2) + k)!)/(Sqrt[π] k!) Integrate[t^(4 k), {t, z, 0}], {k, 0, ∞}]
   -z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -z^4]
```

*et voilà*!

Comment: There is even a simpler analytic answer to your integral (see my post). No need for the theta-function. I do agree with you that MA could have handle elliptic integrals differently.

Answer (score 4):

Many excellent answers has already been given. They do generate the hypergeometric function. I guess the motivation to know it is computational convenience. But let me represent the final result in even simpler form. Maybe it will be useful for you

$$\int_z^0\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}F\!\left(2 \arctan(z)\,\big|\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

The integral form is taken from the solution of J.M. and is computed with the [rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) package

```
Get["Rubi`"]
Int[1/Sqrt[1+t^4],{t,z,0}]
Out[3]= -(((1+z^2) Sqrt[(1+z^4)/(1+z^2)^2] EllipticF[2 ArcTan[z],1/2])/(2 Sqrt[1+z^4]))
```

Now one can compare this result and the function defined by Roman.

```
f[z_]=(-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z],-1]
g[z_]:=-(1/2) EllipticF[2 ArcTan[z],1/2]
```

The result looks quite simple.

Comment: Indeed, your simpler solution can in fact be derived from mine (modulo a constant term), since `FullSimplify[Tan[ArcCos[(z^2 - 1)/(z^2 + 1)]] == Tan[-2 ArcTan[z]] // TrigExpand, 0 < z < 1]` yields `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[z_] = (-1)^(1/4) EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) z], -1];
```

---

**Note** the correspondence is already present in

`Entity["MathematicalFunction", "EllipticF"]["ParticularValues"]`

but with `ArcSin` instead of `ArcSinh`. That can be adapted to the present question by changing z to I*z. The text below is more of an example of how one could use [`DifferentialRootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRootReduce.html) to find the answer.

---

Consider the ansatz :

$$l x^q \, _2F_1\left(a,b;c;w
   x^p\right)$$

We will find the parameters above by equating the [`DifferentialRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html) of the ansatz and of `f`.

The differential equation satisfied by `f`:

**Note**: direct application of `DifferentialRootReduce` does not work in this case.

```
diff =
 Integrate[
        DifferentialRootReduce[D[f[z], z], z]
     ,
     z
     ][[0, 1]][y, x][[1, 1]]
```

$$\left(x^4+1\right) y''(x)+2 x^3 y'(x)$$

A table of differential equations of different ansatz choices for the argument exponent `p` using [`DifferentialRootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRootReduce.html)

**Note** : `⎵=\[UnderBracket]`

**Note**: Included a multiplication by `u*x^r*` as the differential equation is defined up to an overall factor.

```
diff⎵ansatz⎵table = 
 Table[u*x^r*
    DifferentialRootReduce[l*x^q*Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, w*x^p], 
        x][[0, 1]][y, x][[1, 1]] // Expand, {p, 5}]
```

The coefficients of y[x], y'[x], y''[x] for the differential equation that `f` satisfies:

```
eq = DeleteCases[0]@
   Flatten@CoefficientList[
     diff[[0, 1]][y, x][[1, 1]], {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}]~Join~{0}
```

$$\left\{x^4+1,2 x^3,0\right\}$$

table of coefficients for `eq⎵ansatz⎵table` :

```
eq⎵ansatz⎵table = 
 DeleteCases[0]@Flatten@CoefficientList[#, {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}] & /@
   diff⎵ansatz⎵table
```

Finding the value of `r` in the overall `x^r` that multiplies the differential equation of the ansatz :

```
{eq⎵ansatz⎵table[[All, 1]], eq[[1]]}
```

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 u w x^{r+3}-u x^{r+2} \\
 u w x^{r+4}-u x^{r+2} \\
 u w x^{r+5}-u x^{r+2} \\
 u w x^{r+6}-u x^{r+2} \\
 u w x^{r+7}-u x^{r+2} \\
\end{array}
,x^4+1\right\}$$

Notice that only the 4th component for `r=-2` fits both of the exponents on the right hand side. The 4th component corresponds to $p=4$ in `l*x^q*Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, w*x^p]`.
We then use [`SolveAlways`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) to find the other parameters :

```
sol = SolveAlways[
  eq⎵ansatz⎵table[[4]] == eq /. r -> -2, 
  x]
```

Which allows us to find the solutions:

```
l*x^q*Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, w*x^p] /. p -> 4 /. 
  sol // DeleteDuplicates
```

$$\left\{l,l x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4};-x^4\right)\right\}$$

To obtain `l` one could plot the ratio between the ansatz and `f` and notice that `l=-1` looks like a good fit. If we want to be rigorous then we can  use:

`Entity["MathematicalFunction", "EllipticF"]["ParticularValues"]`

where the fomula is already there but with `Arcsin` instead of `ArcSinh`. We can thus use :

```
l*x Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -x^4]/f[x] /. 
  x -> I*(-1)^(3/4)*1 // FunctionExpand
```

`(* -l *)`

to obtain `l=-1`.